Can't import custom python package in my project
I'm trying to create a package in Python using Poetry and then use it in another project. However after importing the package, I'm unable to use it. The project doesn't recognize it.
Library
pyproject.toml:
[tool.poetry]
name = "python-lib-example"
version = "0.5.0"
description = ""
authors = ["xxx"]
readme = "README.md"
packages = [{include = "python_lib_example"}]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"


[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
devpi-client = "^7.1.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api

Test Class:
class PersonInfo:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

    def get_info(self):
        return f'{self.name} is {self.age} years old'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_info()

__init__.py is empty
Project structure:

I build the package this way and upload it to DevPi, which is running in Docker. I then install it into the target project from DevPi.
Target project
pyproject.toml:
[tool.poetry]
name = "python-app-example"
version = "0.0.1"
description = ""
authors = ["xxx"]
readme = "README.md"
package-mode = false

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
python-lib-example = {version = "^0.5.0", source = "mjana"}


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "mjana"
url = "http://localhost:3141/mjana/mjana/+simple"
priority = "supplemental"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api

And now I'm trying import
from python_lib_example import PersonInfo

But it seems that the project doesn't recognize the package, even though the installation from DevPi completes without any issues. Where could I be making a mistake?

The PersonInfo class is located in the namespace of the person_info module. So your import must be:
from python_lib_example.person_info import PersonInfo


You are right, but the application project doesn's see python_lib_example at all
